# CSS layers of backgrounds - upper layer using color opacity

Tags: css, background, gradient

I want to use color opacity using `rgb`,
my problem is that I dont always have the background I want underneath it,
and I can't create other HTML or pseudo elements for having them as backgrounds for the opacity..

So I've been think about using css multiple backgrounds..

The background I want as the first layer is `rgb(0 0 0 / 74%)`

and below it I want to use a gradient `var(--gradient) fixed`,
so the opacity of the `rgb` will be applied on the gradient mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
background: linear-gradient(rgb(0 0 0 / 74%), rgb(0 0 0 / 74%)), var(--gradient) fixed
```

`background-color` are not supported as multiple background,
so it's possible to fake it by creating a linear gradient..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```css
:root{
   --grade: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 50%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
}
#txt::before{
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:18px;
  position:absolute;
  background: var(--grade);
  z-index:-1;
}
#txt{
color:white;
  background-color:rgb(0 0 0 / 24%)
}
```

```html
<div id="txt">This is a Text</div>
```

Comment: "I can't create other HTML or pseudo elements for having them as backgrounds for the opacity.."
otherwise it would have been easier

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible to have multiple layers without creating them.